# Punctuation of "what?" in the middle of a sentence

Tags: punctuation, speech, figures-of-speech

I'm transcribing an interview and the man says,

> "There were, what, 4,000 people at the concert."

I'm not sure how to properly punctuate this. He's asking "What?" in the middle of the sentence as a rhetorical question or perhaps talking to someone off camera. It's hard to say if the full sentence is a question or not. (He's British, if that helps!)

My ideas:

> "There were, what, 4,000 people at the concert?"
>
> "There were -- what? -- 4,000 people at the concert."

Answer (score 1):

If there is no special stress on *what* and it's just a rhetorical stall while the interviewee thought of a number, then use commas.

If there is stress on *what*, i.e. that the number 4000 is somehow remarkable or noteworthy, use m-dashes, no spaces, or n-dashes with a space (follow applicable stylesheet).

If there is stress and with rising intonation suggesting the interviewee really is asking a question, then dashes as above and a question mark.